# RelativeLayout breaks on pre-Marshmallow devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am facing a problem while populating a list view. Following is my layout for a list item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_check_box"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:button="@drawable/btn_check"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_pay_periods_date"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mon Sep 12"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_check_box"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_in"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12:00 am"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_check_box"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_pay_periods_date"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_out"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_in"
        android:text="12:00 am"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_check_box"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_service_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Attendant care service service service"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_in"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_in"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_duration"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_duration" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_activities"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Housework, shopping, shopping, shopping"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_pay_periods_service_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_out"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_out"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_duration"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_duration"
        android:visibility="visible"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemPayPeriodsNotesLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_pay_periods_activities"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_out"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_duration"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_duration"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_img_tag"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tag"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_notes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="made trip to CVC"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5h 00m"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_in"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_pay_periods_time_in"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_img_submit_check_icon"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:tint="@color/blue"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_pay_periods_entry_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_img_submit_check_icon"
        android:text="Rejected"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks on Marshmallow and Nougat devices

[Not overlapping views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFGhP.png)

And this is how it looks on Lollipop and pre lollipop devices

[Overlapping views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hllLw.jpg)

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Or anybody have faced such issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: one thing I see is that you reference a view like this: `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_pay_periods_check_box"`. But only use the `+` if the view is not created until then. For example, your first checkBox references :  `android:layout_below="@+id/item_pay_periods_date"` that´s correct, because the textView you are referenced is under the checkBox. But the textView references the checkBox, which is above and so it exists. So you must reference existing views wihtout `+` like `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_pay_periods_check_box"`

Comment: The next thing is that you say, the checkBox should be under the textView. But then, the textView should to the right of the checkBox, I am not sure if this is not a little bit confusing for the system...

Comment: Thankk you sir. I will try this out.

Comment: ok, I don´t know if this is the cause of your problem. The thing is, wrong things could work in prior versions of android, and then after new system comes out, it doesn´t.